# Why is my ActiveStorage service setting being ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rails-activestorage

I have the followings files in my project.

**config/storage.yml**

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

google:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("google-cloud-storage-credentials.json") %>
  project: "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PROJECT_ID"] %>"
  bucket: "matomeishi"
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :google
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :google
```

For some reason, when trying to attach files, the following error happens.

```
StandardError: Missing configuration for the local Active Storage service. 
Configurations available for the test and google services..
```

It seems the application is not considering my `config.active_storage.service`...
Did anyone encounter the same problem? Is it a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some Active Storage in the `config/application.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after some inspection.
It seems that Rails uses the same service that was used for previous file uploads for some reason (in order to not break the current files URL maybe).

- The first version of `storage.yml` looked like this. I then uploaded some files using `local` service to GCS.

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("google-cloud-storage-credentials.json") %>
  project: "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PROJECT_ID"] %>"
  bucket: "matomeishi"
```

- After reviewing my code, I renamed `local` to `google` because I thought that was more appropriate. I also changed the configuration in my `config/development.rb` from `config.active_storage.service = :local` to `config.active_storage.service = :google`.

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

google:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("google-cloud-storage-credentials.json") %>
  project: "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PROJECT_ID"] %>"
  bucket: "matomeishi"
```

- After restarting my server and trying to upload some files again. The below error happens. It seems that it is still trying to access the `local` service even though it is not mentioned anywhere in the configuration.

```
StandardError: Missing configuration for the local Active Storage service. 
Configurations available for the test and google services..
```

**Reason**
The reason is that Rails checks first the `service_name` column in the `active_storage_blobs` table and seems to use it instead of the service set in the configuration.

**Solution**

I then tried to update all the `service_name` of the existing records from `local` to `google` and see if that would fix the problem! And it did

After that, upon uploading files with ActiveStorage, it correctly uses the `google` service.

Answer (score 0):

add to `config/storage.yml` configuration for local env

for example:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Comment: OP wants Google storage, not local one

Comment: oops....) sorry